# Convert float to decimal, wrong value

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal

I have a `float` number: `10071072872302` and I need to convert it to `decimal`.

```
float number = 10071072872302f;
var convertNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(number);
```

I get the value: `10071070000000` which is *Wrong*.

If I convert it to `double` first, and then convert it to `decimal`:

```
float number = 10071072872302f;
var convertNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDouble(number));
```

I get the value: `10071073357824` which is also *Wrong*.

If I just convert `float` to `double`:

```
float number = 10071072872302f;
var convertNumber = Convert.ToDouble(number);
```

I get the value: `10071073357824` which is *Wrong*.

I am really confused. My company's database is designed with `decimal` data type. I need to programmatically calculate the value of the data according to the pre-configured formula, I need to use the `NCalc` library which returns the float data type. Unfortunately, I can't convert `float` to decimal`.

Could anyone help me with this impasse?

**EDIT**
I want to clarify why I need to convert float to decimal.

To get a value, I need to calculate the expression like: `ISA16+ISA8+ISNULL(MAX((ABS(BSMS10)-ABS(BSMS10_)),0),0)`

After taking the data in the database to replace the expression, I have an expression like this: `10071072872302+872302+MAX((ABS(-072872302)-ABS(2302)),0)`

To calculate the value of this expression, I use the `NCalc` library

```
private static object CalculateString(string formula)
    {
        var expression = new Expression(formula);

        expression.EvaluateFunction += (name, args) =>
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case "ABS":
                    args.Result = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(args.Parameters[0].Evaluate()));
                    break;
                case "MAX":
                    args.Result = Math.Max(Convert.ToDouble(args.Parameters[0].Evaluate()), Convert.ToDouble(args.Parameters[1].Evaluate()));
                    break;
            }
        };

        var value = expression.Evaluate();
        return value;
    }
```

Expressions come in many forms. However, to check the value, I tried checking with a number of `10071072872302`

```
var result = CalculateString("10071072872302");
```

The result I get is a float value, so I need to convert it to decimal to match the data type in the database. That is why I posed the question above.

Comment: The *float* type can store up to 7 digits of precision.  So what you got is correct.  Consider *double* or *decimal*.  Clearly you'll favor the latter, use 10071072872302m as a literal.

Comment: `10071072872302` cannot be stored in a float without a loss of precision.

Comment: `number.ToString("F")` results in 10071070000000.00. So it's wrong from the get go.

Comment: Actually, the float value I got from a third party, so I need to convert to decimal. But it's too difficult

Comment: It doesn't matter where you got it.  That value cannot fit inside a float.  You will not get back the missing precision by converting it.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a float number: 10071072872302.
>
> `float number = 10071072872302f;`

Unfortunately, that's too late, `float` has no exact representation for 10071072872302 . So the nearest *machine number* that's the most close is :  10071073357824. So that's the value that is actually stored in your variable.

see for instance : [FloatConverter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

You must strive to get another representation, not `float` (`string`, `decimal`, or other bigint library), to get this number.

Note that `double` *should* be actually ok *for this precise number* (`double number = 10071072872302` ), but I wouldn't rely on floating point number type (`float` or `double`) to store an exact value in any case.

See also this generic Q&A : [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @MinhGiang Ok, this is much more precise, thanks for the edit. I don't know NCalc, but a quick search showed me that there is a `Convert.ToDecimal()` function, can you try to use it instead of `ToDouble()` ?

Comment: _`The result I get is a float value`_ : this my lack of knowledge of NCalc speaking : How do you know it's a `float` (as in the alias of `System.Float`)  ? The returned signature of your method is `object`, so I can't really be sure of what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I already been solved my problem. I found `Jint` library instead of NCalc

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint

```
static Engine engine = new Engine()
             .Execute("function ABS(number){return Math.abs(number);}")
             .Execute("function MAX(a,b){return Math.max(a,b);}")
             .Execute("function Max(a,b){return Math.max(a,b);}")
             .Execute("function ISNULL(a,b){return a==null?b:a;}")
             .Execute("function Divide(a,b){return a==null||b==null||b==0?null:a/b;}");

    private static object CalculateString(string formula)
    {
        var result = engine
            .Execute(formula)
            .GetCompletionValue()
            .ToObject();
        return result == null ? null : (object)Convert.ToDecimal(result);
    }
```

It's works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into two problems here:

- **Decimal vs. Binary.** NCalc appears to be calculating expressions using `float` values. But note that `float` and `double` are binary floating-point number types, and not all decimal numbers can be represented exactly in a binary number type (regardless of its length); examples include 0.1 and 0.3. (In comparison, `decimal` is a decimal floating-point number type.) If NCalc is parsing the decimal numbers in your expressions into binary number types such as `float` or `double`, then there is a risk of rounding error due to the need to convert certain decimal numbers to those types, even if the decimal numbers in your expressions have relatively few digits.
- **Limited precision.**`float`, `double`, and `decimal` are limited-precision number types. For example, `float` has a precision of 24 bits (about 7 decimal digits) and `decimal` has a precision of about 28 decimal digits. If your expressions have numbers with more digits than a number type can handle, then there will be a loss of precision on those numbers once converted to that type. On the other hand, `BigInteger` is a number type with effectively unlimited precision, so this may be viable if you're only working with integers.

I'm not familiar with NCalc, but see if you can set NCalc to parse and process numbers in the `decimal` number type (provided all the numbers you care about have 28 decimal digits or less). Provided all the numbers in your expressions are integers, and nothing in your expressions can cause fractions to occur in a calculation, you can also use `BigInteger` instead of `decimal` if NCalc supports it. If NCalc doesn't support `decimal` or `BigInteger`, then you may need to use another expression parsing library.